# default a specific user value on form load in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, select

Am trying to do this for add assignment:
for normal teachers: there an option to select subjects as a drop down option.
for teaching assistants: when they click on 'add assignment' the fields
(name, subject) are automatically loaded on the form as these specific teachers only have 1 subject assigned to them.. currently i am console logging from component didmount.
how do i set it so when they click it loads on the form automatically?

```
    this.props.getAvailableteachers()
      .then(() => {
        if (this.props.teachers.length === 1) {
           console.log(this.props.teachers);
        } else {
          console.log("Length is >>>>>>>>>> 1"); 
        } })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

and for the select form

```
                  type='text'
                  name='teachers'
                  colSize='8'
                  id='teachers'
                  onChange={this.teacherChange}
                  options={teacherOptions}
                />
```

right now it just console logs the result.. i need it on the form tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below, May work for you :

```
  this.props.getAvailableteachers()
      .then(() => {
        if (this.props.teachers.length === 1) {
           console.log(this.props.teachers);
           this.setState({selectedId : set_your_id_here}) 
        } else {
          console.log("Length is >>>>>>>>>> 1"); 
        } })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

and for the select form

```
              type='text'
              name='teachers'
              colSize='8'
              id='teachers'
              onChange={this.teacherChange}
              options={teacherOptions}
              selected={this.state.selectedId}   
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the props data to `value` property as below

```
              type='text'
              name='teachers'
              colSize='8'
              id='teachers'
              onChange={this.teacherChange}
              options={teacherOptions}
              value={this.props.teachers}
              selected={this.props.teachers}
            />
```

Comment: could you please post output from console.log(this.props.teachers)?